# Callback in Twitter widget

Tags: wordpress, twitter, callback, widget

Does anyone know how to include a callback in this Twitter widget? Any input would be much appreciated.

```
<script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+"://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs"); </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Twitter’s widgets JavaScript fires events on initialization and after a viewer interacts with a widget: https://dev.twitter.com/web/javascript/events.

You have to load the javascript yourself in the `<head>` of your page:

```
<script src="http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" id="twitter-wjs"></script>
```

Then add some Javascript, like:

```
twttr.ready(function (twttr) {
    twttr.events.bind(
    'rendered',
    function (ev) {
      // callback code
    });
});
```

You can see an example [at the end of this JS](http://stylebydeluna.fr/wp-content/themes/Activello-master/inc/js/functions.min.js) and the result on the "GET THE DIRECT" section of this [page](http://stylebydeluna.fr/)